# FileNotFoundException when writing new xsd file

Tags: java, xml, file, xsd, filenotfoundexception

I have parsed a batch of XML Schema files using a DOMparser. I than added several annotations, which are essential for the application I am creating. I then want to write these new "preprocessed" files to a new location, and I get a FileNotFound exception (access denied).

Here's the snippet of code where I am writing the file:

```
Transformer tFormer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

// Set output file to xml
tFormer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");

// Write the document back to the file
Source source = new DOMSource(document);
File preprFile = new File(newPath(xmlFile));
    // The newPath function is a series of String operations that result in a new
    relative path

try {
    // Create file if it doesn't already exist;
    preprFile.mkdirs();
    preprFile.createNewFile();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Result result = new StreamResult(preprFile);
tFormer.transform(source, result);
```

And the error I am getting is the following:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: absolutePathHere (Access is denied)
```

Which points to this line in the above snippet :

```
tFormer.transform(source, result);
```

I'm using a Windows machine (read somewhere that that can be the source of this error), and I've already tried turning UAC off, but no success.

I was thinking maybe the createNewFile() method doesn't release the file after it's been made, but was unable to find more information about that.

Here's hoping StackOverflow can come to my rescue once again.

Comment: Which path is shown? Source or result? Is the file being created?

Comment: you tried this in local system or some other server? Please give the xml path your are using in File object.

Comment: The directory is created, and it appears the file is created as a directory as well, which I find particularly odd.

I'm running this on a local system, and the path I'm using is 

`target\zips\kbo_services_schemas\be\fgov\economie\kbo\R16\WSReportKBO\preprocessed\wsreportkbo_messages.xsd`

Well, at least that's the output from getPath. The input is the same but with forward slashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
File preprFile = new File(directory1/directory2/directory3/file.xsd);
File directory = new File(directory1/directory2/directory3/);

try {
// Create file if it doesn't already exist;
    directory.mkdirs();
    preprFile.createNewFile();                              
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably running under a user account that doesn't have the rights to that directory.

Comment: which operating system you are using ? are you using applets in this situation ?

Comment: I am not using applets, and I'm running under Windows 7, with UAC disabled and I should have rights to that directory, because from inside windows UI, I can fully manage this directory.

Answer (score 0):

You said "The directory is created, and it appears the file is created as a directory as well". So I think it creates directory named 'wsreportkbo_messages.xsd'

It gives you error may be because you are trying to read directory. You can list files in directories using **listFiles()**.

You cannot open and read a directory, use the **isFile()** and **isDirectory()** methods to distinguish between files and folders.